# Could not get unknown property 'compileSdkVersion' for root project 'Cropimg' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

i am using a library and when i sync my project iam getting this error
Could not get unknown property 'compileSdkVersion' for root project 'Cropimg' of type org.gradle.api.Project. 
my gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
gradle-builds
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {

compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName PUBLISH_VERSION
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}


android.libraryVariants
publishing {
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {

        groupId PUBLISH_GROUP_ID
        artifactId PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID
        version PUBLISH_VERSION + '-SNAPSHOT'

        //artifact bundleRelease
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile("com.android.support:exifinterface:$supportLibraryVersion") {
    transitive = false
}
}
```

Comment: the issue is here: rootProject.compileSdkVersion.

Comment: yes it is there how can i solve this error

Answer (score 6):

In your project build.gradle declare compileSdkVersion

`

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'

 }
```

`

Comment: compileSdkVersion 27